# How to safely transfer some space from linux to windows?

Tags: windows, partitioning, fedora

I have windows(40gb) and fedora 33(80gb) installed on my SSD.

Windows has about 10gb of free space and Fedora has 35gb, and I would like to transfer some of free gigabytes from Fedora to Windows.

(Visually)
Now my disk is divided like this:

```
|--Windows(used) 30gb--| |--Windows(free) 10gb--| |--Fedora(used) 45gb--| |--Fedora(free) 35gb--|
```

And I want total space to be distributed like this:

```
|--Windows(used) 30gb--| |--Windows(free) 30gb--| |--Fedora(used) 45gb--| |--Fedora(free) 15gb--|
```

How can this be done safely?

Answer (score 0):

I did this with mounting the Windows(free) section when I use my linux (Ubuntu). In my case it was only to add a line in `/etc/fstab` for the mount of this partition.

Had some trouble as Windows changed over to shutdown with hibernating the drives. Have now a part solution for it, because I would like to start the Systemdrive for Windows with hibernating function on and the second drive - you named windows(free) without hibernating and shutting down for every shutdown. I had to use the function `powercfg /h off` as else the windows system was blocking a rw-mount by hybernating the drive. You may check after with `powercfg /a` if your setting has been taken.

But I don't know If you are able to do so as I do not know if you drive your Windows or your Fedora as a VM so that you've got both aktiv by the same time because I choose while booting the system or tell it to restart in Windows from linux direct.

Else if both is running I would use wscp to do it as fedora does easy ssh and with wscp you are able to copy some how all what you want over.

Comment: Just in case, I apologize if I described my question unclearly. What I need is rather like allocating free space from fedora using gparted and moving it to left (and then adding this space to Windows with its disk creation tool). However, I do not know if this is the right way (whether GRUB will work properly, etc.).

Comment: Than you need first move the data in your Fedora together and resize the partition to move it. Then you may extend your Windows partition. There it could be tricky, that you need both gparted to resize the partition itself and because of Windows would recognise you need than a Startmedium for Windows to repair you Windows but maybe your Windows is able to allocate the free space next to its drive. But I did this some times and when I touched a part that was recognised by Windows it gave me always some need of repairing the Windows. But I did never lost data by doing this. First save your data.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have two partitions, Windows and Fedora.

This is the procedure to follow:

- Take backups, as partition editing can cause damage in case of an error
- Boot GParted (or a similar Linux utility) and:

  - Resize the Fedora partition to, say, 55 GB.
    This will create unallocated space of 25 GB following the Fedora partition.
  - Move the Fedora partition to the end of the disk so the unallocated space
    is between the Windows and Fedora partitions
- Boot Windows, enter Disk Management, and resize its disk to the maximum.